# How can I propagate throwable to the Completable's next chain?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am developing an Android app using RxJava.

I have some API call chains.

1. verify
2. consume

```java
val verify = Completable.error(Exception("TEST"))
            .doOnSubscribe { Log.d(TAG, "1. verify") }
            .doOnComplete{ Log.d(TAG, "1. verify - success") }
            .doOnError { Log.e(TAG, "1. verify - failed: ${it.message}") }
            .retryWhen { attempts ->
                attempts.zipWith(
                    Flowable.range(1, 3), BiFunction<Throwable, Int, Long> { t, i ->
                        if (i <= 3) {
                            1L
                        } else {
                            throw t
                        }
                    }
                ).flatMap {
                    Flowable.timer(it, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                }
            }

// 2. consume
val consume = Single.just("SUCCESS")
    .doOnSubscribe { Log.d(TAG, "2. consume") }
    .doOnSuccess { Log.d(TAG, "2. consume - success") }
    .doOnError { Log.e(TAG, "2. consume - failed: ${it.message}", it) }

disposable.add(
    verify.andThen (consume)
        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
        .observeOn(uiScheduler)
        .subscribe({
            Log.d(TAG, "done")
        }, { t ->
            Log.e(TAG, "failed: ${t.message}", t)
        })
);
```

What I excepted is...

"verify" should be called 3 times every 1 seconds.

After 3 retries failed, it should be done with Error.

But in my case, "consume" was run too.

Why?

I want to skip "consume" if "verify" is failed!

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your code is not failing.

With `Flowable.range(1, 3)` you create a range from 1 to 3 so the else part of your code is never reached.

Try with `Flowable.range(1, 4)` and you will see the correct behaviour.